# JS: import an array module into main script and not HTML

Tags: javascript, arrays, import, module

I’m new to JavaScript. I’ve looked for an answer to my problem, but can’t figure this out.

Likewise, I have an array of different options (for a text adventure game) that I want to import into the main JS script. The issue is that I am calling different options from the array in the main script, and it’s not working.

The answers I found on the internet would work for importing functions from a module into HTML code, but that isn’t what I’m looking for.

Here is the code that **is** working:

```
const textElement = document.getElementById('text');
const buttonOptionsElement = document.getElementById('buttonOptions');

// keep track of what the character has on them

let state = {}
// function to start the game
function startGame() {
 state = {}
 showTextNode(1)

}

function showTextNode(textNodeIndex) {
 const textNode = textNodes.find(textNode => textNode.id === textNodeIndex)
 textElement.innerText = textNode.text
 while (buttonOptions.firstChild) {
   buttonOptions.removeChild(buttonOptions.firstChild)
 }

 textNode.options.forEach(option => {
   if(showOption(option)) {
     const button = document.createElement('button')
     button.innerText = option.text
     button.classList.add('btn')
     button.addEventListener('click', () => selectOption(option))
     buttonOptions.appendChild(button)
   }
 })
}

function showOption(option) {
 return option.requiredState == null || option.requiredState(state)
}

// function to get the element clicked
function selectOption(option) {
 const nextTextNodeId = option.nextText
 if (nextTextNodeId <= 0) {
   return startGame()
 }
 state = Object.assign(state, option.setState)
 showTextNode(nextTextNodeId)
}

const textNodes = [
 {
   id: 1,
   text: 'First scenario',
   options: [
     {
       text: 'Take goo',
       setState: { blueGoo: true},
       nextText: 2
     },
     {
       text: 'leave the goo',
     }
   ]
 },
 {
   id: 2,
   text: 'this is the second scenario.',
   options: [
     {
       text: 'trade the goo for a sword',
       requiredState: (currentState) => currentState.blueGoo,
       setState: { blueGoo: false, sword: true},
       nextText: 3
     }
]

startGame();
```

The code that **isn’t** working is simply the same thing, but instead of having the `textNodes` array in the `main.js`, I have it in a separate file. I import it in place of the `const textNodes = [{},...,{}]` with the following line:

```
import { textNodes } from './modules/scenario.js'
```

Comment: make sure you import the other js directly into the HTML page even if it is used in another place js also main.js must be declared second in the main HTML page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the issue... It’s ridiculous, it’s just that in the HTML I typed `type="modules"` instead of `type="module"`.

Answer (score 0):

Emm, reputation is not enough to comment. Basically you need to review the JS module documentation first for your debugging session. Possibly 2 places you need to check:

1. For the module js file, you need to declar it as module in HTML.

> `<script type="module" src="main.js"></script>`

2. You need to export corresponding functions at scenario.js.

Comment: I declared the module in the HTML first, and then declared the main.js, as well as exporting the array in the module, but it still isn’t working. Is it possible to export an array in JavaScript? Because all the answer I get are talking about "corresponding functions"... what i’m exporting is not a function, that might be the issue.

Comment: Module is mainly designed for external functions. If you just want to get array from other JS file, just make a global variable will do. If the array is from exported JS, simply make a small function to return it.